# Questions about Microsft Academics Knowledge API

Tags: azure-cognitive-services, academic-graph

We would like to use the Microsoft academics API for our research. There are 2 things we're struggling with.

1. We were under the impression that any data available on https://academic.microsoft.com/ should be available in the API. However, we can't find any identifier for the abstract of a paper here https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/academic-services/project-academic-knowledge/reference-paper-entity-attributes. Is this something that is foreseen to be added to the API in the foreseeable future? How can we close this 'gap' at the moment?
2. Is it possible to do exclusion queries? We noticed that at the moment we can use AND and OR in our query expressions. We've also tried adding NOT but to no avail. Is this something that is possible or can be achieved in a certain way?

Thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

@Diederik Currently there is no guarantee that data available on the academic site is also available through the API, although we are working to ensure the same is achievable.

The complete paper abstracts (incl. original formatting) are available via the [Inverted Abstract (“IA”)](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/academic-services/project-academic-knowledge/reference-paper-entity-attributes#invertedabstract) attribute, and need to be reconstructed by the user. This is because of legal constraints as documented in the [FAQ](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/academic-services/graph/resources-faq#what-format-are-paper-abstracts-published-in).

Also, Exclusion queries are currently not supported by the query expression syntax.